# How to get Arraylist<HashMap<String, String>> from AsyncTask through onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to put storelist into StoreList variable. But it is not working.
`doInBackground` method is working perfectly but `onPostexecute` is not working.

Here is my code,

```
public class guest_main extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
    Location mCurrentLocation, mDestination;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    String currentLon, currentLat;
    private ListView mListView = null;
    private ListViewAdapter mAdapter = null;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> StoreList;

    class BackgroundWorker3 extends AsyncTask<String, Void,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>  {
        Context context;
        AlertDialog alertDialog;


        BackgroundWorker3(Context ctx) {
            context = ctx;
        }

        JSONArray store = null;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> storeList;

        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... params) {
            String type = params[0];
            storeList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            if (type.equals("Select2")) {
                try {

                    String link = "...";
                    URL url = new URL(link);
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                    wr.flush();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String json;
                    while ((json = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(json);
                    }
                    String s = sb.toString().trim();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                    store = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
                    for (int i = 0; i < store.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = store.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name = c.getString("name");
                        String tel = c.getString("tel");
                        String latitude = c.getString("latitude");
                        String longitude = c.getString("longitude");
                        HashMap<String, String> stores = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        stores.put("name", name);
                        stores.put("tel", tel);
                        stores.put("latitude", latitude);
                        stores.put("longitude", longitude);
                        storeList.add(stores);
                    }
                    return storeList;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }

            }
            return storeList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList) {



            StoreList = arrayList;

        }
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.guest_main, container, false);
        StoreList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        getData();
        buildGoogleApiClient();

        mListView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.mList);
        mAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity());

       for(int i=0; i<StoreList.size(); i++){
           HashMap<String, String> each = StoreList.get(i);
           String name = each.get("name");
           String tel = each.get("tel");
           String lat = each.get("latitude");
           String lon = each.get("longitude");
           mDestination.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(lat).doubleValue());
           mDestination.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(lon).doubleValue());
           float distance = mCurrentLocation.distanceTo(mDestination);
           mAdapter.addItem(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sin), name, tel,Float.toString(distance));
       }
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);



        Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

        return v;
    }
    public void getData(){
        BackgroundWorker3 bk2 = new BackgroundWorker3(getActivity());

            bk2.execute("Select2");



    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.button1:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), gmenu_list.class);
                startActivity(intent);

        }
    }


    private class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView mIcon;

        public TextView mText;

        public TextView mDate;

        public TextView mDistance;
    }

    private class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext = null;
        private ArrayList<g_ListData> mListData = new ArrayList<g_ListData>();

        public ListViewAdapter(Context mContext) {
            super();
            this.mContext = mContext;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mListData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mListData.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public void addItem(Drawable icon, String mTitle, String mDate, String mDistance){
            g_ListData addInfo = null;
            addInfo = new g_ListData();
            addInfo.mIcon = icon;
            addInfo.mTitle = mTitle;
            addInfo.mDate = mDate;
            addInfo.mDistance = mDistance;

            mListData.add(addInfo);
        }

        public void remove(int position){
            mListData.remove(position);
            dataChange();
        }

        public void sort(){
            Collections.sort(mListData, g_ListData.ALPHA_COMPARATOR);
            dataChange();
        }

        public void dataChange(){
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gmenu_list_item, null);

                holder.mIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mImage);
                holder.mText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mText);
                holder.mDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mDate);
                holder.mDistance = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mDistance);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            g_ListData mData = mListData.get(position);

            if (mData.mIcon != null) {
                holder.mIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mIcon.setImageDrawable(mData.mIcon);
            }else{
                holder.mIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            holder.mText.setText(mData.mTitle);
            holder.mDate.setText(mData.mDate);
            holder.mDate.setText(mData.mDistance);

            return convertView;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(100000); // Update location every second
        try{
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);


            mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                    mGoogleApiClient);}catch (SecurityException e){
        }
        if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
            currentLat = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
            currentLon = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        currentLat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        currentLon = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
    synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok..The problem is in your case that the Async task runs on separate thread from UI thread So when you call BackgroundWorker3 in getData method then UI thread doesn't wait for Async task response(separte thread) and StoreList have null value. So you see StoreList doesn't have any value and in listView nothing will show.

Write this code in onPostExecute method not in onCreate..

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList) {



    StoreList = arrayList;
    mListView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.mList);
   mAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity());

for(int i=0; i<StoreList.size(); i++){
   HashMap<String, String> each = StoreList.get(i);
   String name = each.get("name");
   String tel = each.get("tel");
   String lat = each.get("latitude");
   String lon = each.get("longitude");
   mDestination.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(lat).doubleValue());
   mDestination.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(lon).doubleValue());
   float distance = mCurrentLocation.distanceTo(mDestination);
   mAdapter.addItem(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sin), name, tel,Float.toString(distance));
 }
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I changed my onPostExecute as you told me, but now it stops when this UI shows up and it still doesnt show my hashmap on the listview ...

Comment: Who did downvote for my answer..Can tell me that how it's not relevant answer.